# php - Prevent call to other function from changing headers

Tags: php, header, echo, content-type

I have the following code:

```
$result = array('output'=>'success');
header("Content-Type: application/json; Charset=UTF-8");
echo json_encode($result);
```

However, when I call another function as follows, the header is changed to `text/html`

```
$myfunc->call();
$result = array('output'=>'success');
header("Content-Type: application/json; Charset=UTF-8");
echo json_encode($result);
```

Basically `$myfunc->call();` changes the header and echoes text. This is causing my code to fail. How can I ignore the change of header and output from `$myfunc->call();`?

Comment: The only way to "ignore" the output from a function/method is not to call it, or to use the `return` keyword, rather than `echo` or `print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is to pass a parameter to that function indicating whether the header code should be executed or not, then wrapping that piece of code in a conditional. However, thats only if you are free to change the function. Otherwise you are stuck because you can't set the headers twice.

```
function call($setHeaders=true) {
    ...
    if ($setHeaders) {
        // Code for seting the header
    }
}
```

Comment: >>  you are stuck because you can't set the headers twice. OK.